# how to make user to select first option before moving to the rest of the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 options in my html page. first is checkbox, second is radiobutton and the third one is slider. User should first select checkbox ,then radiobutton and the slider. how do i write condition for this using jquery?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please make your question clear.

Comment: hide two other intially and when user check/uncheck the check-box then show/hide them

Comment: show your code first

Comment: hide elements and show them only if the previous element has values\

Comment: I suggest you have a quick view on JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check with [Jquery change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) that if input change from unchecked to checked then do what ever you want. for example

```js
//Disabled By Default
$('#radio input').prop("disabled", true);
$('#slider input').prop("disabled", true);

// Check if checkbox changed unchecked to checked
$('#checkbox input').on('change', function() {
  //than unchecked the radio button
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $('#radio input').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});

// Check if radio changed unchecked to checked
$('#radio input').on('change', function() {
  //than unchecked the slider
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $('#slider input').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> checkbox</label>
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> checkbox</label>
</div>
<div id="radio">
  <label>
        <input type="radio"> radio</label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio"> radio</label>
</div>
<div id="slider">
  <label>
        <input type="range"> Slider</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether your checkbox is checked or not and then can take decision based on this

```
if($('#yourcheckboxid').prop("checked") == true)
{
     //allow to do other stuff
}
else
{
    //code to prevent other activities
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resetradio (checkbox) {
    var buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('chkPassPort');
    radios[0].checked = true;
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        buttons.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        buttons.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById("sliderDiv");
        dvPassport.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
```

```css
.buttons {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="featured_ad" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="resetradio(this)">Check to display Radio buttons
<hr />
<div class="buttons">      
    
<span>Select "Yes" to display Slider</span>

<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>

<hr />
<div id="sliderDiv" style="display: none">
    This is slider
    <div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#f00">
    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```